# Sort an array and displaying its correspondent

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, variables, sorting

So we got the values (INT) :

```
V1 , V2 , V3 , V4
```

And the text :

```
Text1 , Text2 , Text3 , Text4
```

We will order the values and echo corespondent Text instead of values.

Let's take an example :

```
(variables) :  V1 = 1 , V2 = 30 , V3 = 2 , V4 = 4
(text) :  Banana ,   Cake  ,  Apple , Patato
```

Will result ->

```
V1 , V3 , V4 , V2
```

after they are ordered but we will display text instead of our current result .
So the final echo is :

```
Banana , Apple , Patato , Cake . (will echo them into a table)
```

Note : Some of the values can be equal !

So far i tried with 3 arrays :

```
($text_array) text , ($arr1) V1[...] , and ($arr2) V1[...]
```

(same as second because I use sort($array); on it).

I tried to echo with :

```
echo $text_array[array_search($arr1[0], $arr2)];
```

but this will make the text repeat if values are the same.

I am sorry if I did not make myself clear ... it's really hard to explain.

#

```
    UPDATE
```

#

It looks like this :

```
$V1 = $vars[1] + $vars[29] + $vars[30];
$V2 = $vars[6] + $vars[19] + $vars[40];
$V3 = $vars[14] + $vars[15] + $vars[44];
$V4 = $vars[0] + $vars[22] + $vars[37];
..........................................
$V15 = $vars[3] + $vars[28] + $vars[31];
```

Text array :

```
$valori = array(("Altruismul", "Simtul estetic", "Creativitatea", "Stimularea intelectuala", "Reusita obiectivata", "Independenta", "Prestigiul", "Conducerea altora", "Avantajele materiale", "Siguranta", "Ambianta de la locul de munca", "Relatiile cu superiorii", "Relatiile cu colegii", "Stilul de viata pe care-l asigura profesia", "Varietate");
```

Tried :

```
$arr = array("Altruismul" => $V1 , "Simtul estetic" => $V2 , "Creativitatea" => $V3 , "Stimularea intelectuala" => $V4 , "Reusita obiectivata" => $V5 , "Independenta" => $V6 , "Prestigiul" => $V7 , "Conducerea altora" => $V8 , "Avantajele materiale" => $V9 , "Siguranta" => $V10 , "Ambianta de la locul de munca" => $V11 , "Relatiile cu superiorii" => $V12 , "Relatiile cu colegii" => $V13 , "Stilul de viata pe care-l asigura profesia" => $V14 , "Varietate" => $V15);
            asort($arr);
```

Did not work well.

Comment: you can use an array to store text and values. `array('v1'=>'Cake','v2'=>'Banana','v3'=>'Potato','v4'=>'Apple')` and sort array

Comment: It did not echo what I needed. There were no strings ! And I need $V1 , $V2 , $V3 , $V4 . It should be array( $V1 => 'Cake' ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're trying to say is that you have two arrays that are linked, and you want to sort one and use that sorting to output the second. If so, try this:

```
$amount = array(1 => 1, 2 => 30, 3 => 2, 4 => 4);
$food = array(1 => 'Banana', 2 => 'Cake', 3 => 'Apple', 4 => 'Patato');
asort($amount);

foreach($amount as $key => $val) {
    echo "{$food[$key]} - $val\n";
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
$food = array('Banana' => 1, 'Cake' => 30, 'Apple' => 2, 'Patato' => 4);
asort($food);

foreach($food as $item => $val) {
    echo "$item - $val\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have a unique set of keys:

```
$texts = array_unique($texts);  // assuming $texts is your foods
```

Then, you want to combine the two:

```
$combined = array_combine($texts,
                          array($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4 /* ... you get the idea */);
```

Then, you want to sort based on the keys:

```
ksort($combined);
```

Then you can print in order:

```
foreach($combined as $food, $val)
{
    echo "$food is at $val";
}
```

If you don't like `ksort`, you can always reverse the order of the arrays in the `array_combine` function and then simply use regular `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$int_array = array('$v1' => 2 , '$v2' => 30 , '$v3' => 4 , '$v4' => 10);
$string_array = array('banana' , 'cake' , 'apple' , 'potato');

//First , sort the int_array by value. (low to hight)
$int_array = asort($int_array);

//Second , echo string according to sorted int_array
foreach($int_array as $v => $num)
{
 echo $string_array[ substr($v , 2 , 1) - 1 ];
}
```

Works for you?

Comment: please update us if you found a useful answer to your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are unique, then you can use an associative array:

```
<?php
$data = array(
  1=>"Banana",
  2=>"Apple",
  4=>"Patato",
  30=>"Cake");

//sort the data by the keys if you want
aksort($data);
//Then access it like normal
echo $data[2]; //outputs "Apple"
```

If your values are not unique, then you are going to have a harder time. One way is to use a multidimensional array with a lookup function.

```
<?php
$data = array(
          array(1,"Banana"),
          array(2,"Apple"),
          array(4,"Patato"),
          array(30,"Cake")
        );

echo lookup($data,30); //Outputs "Cake"

function lookup($arr,$key) {
   foreach($arr as $a) {
     if($a[0] == $key)
       return $a[1];
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

And you would want to modify the lookup() function to handle the duplicate values like you want, my function is just going to output the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)? It will sort multiple column arrays without breaking their correspondence, which looks like what you want.

Though nowadays I have a strong preference for row arrays, which is how most tabular data is stored in programming languages and is thus a more 'natural' way:

```
array(
  array('variable' => 1,  'text' => 'Banana'),
  array('variable' => 30, 'text' => 'Cake'  ),
  ...
)
```

(add or remove arrays or indirection as per your liking, but the invariant is that mainArray[0] contains a full row's worth of data (i.e. both V1 and Text1 in some array hierarchy))

...and use a [functional sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort($mainArray, function($left, $right) {
    if ($left['variable'] < $right['variable'])
        return -1;
    else if ($left['variable'] == $right['variable'])
        return 0;
    else
        return +1;
});
```